# Facebook Conversion API Error: Subcode 2804036

Tags: facebook, lead

I've automated the lead conversion through Conv API

Sending a payload to "https://graph.facebook.com/..../events", i got an error code 100 with subcode 2804036

Unfortunately for u, it gave me an italian error but i think it could be "error_user_title":"Invalid Lead ID"

I google everywhere this subcode but i never heard abount it, event in the official [handling error page](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/guides/error-handling/)

I succesfully sent over 10k events per day with the same .net function

10k times successfully sent, some times nope, with this error

Here the response error

`{"error":{"message":"Invalid parameter","type":"OAuthException", "code":100,"error_subcode":2804036,"is_transient":false, "error_user_title":"ID contatto non valido", "error_user_msg":"Uno o pi\u00f9 dei tuoi ID contatto non sono validi o sono stati eliminati. Tutto il tuo gruppo di eventi potrebbe essere rifiutato se ci sono uno o pi\u00f9 ID contatto non validi. L'ID contatto \u00e8 un numero a 15-16 cifre generato da Meta. Puoi verificare che i tuoi ID contatto siano corretti da qui: https:\/\/developers.facebook.com\/docs\/marketing-api\/conversions-api\/conversion-leads-integration\/how-to-find-the-lead-id","fbtrace_id":"idddddd"}}`

I'm working on .Net Framework 4.7.2
it worked fine for almost 2 years